# Installing Kali Pi using all available storage space?

Tags: raspbian, linux, filesystem, kali

Is there any way to install kali linux for raspberry pi using all space that is available on the micrSD card initially or do you HAVE to go back later and resize partitions in order to utilize the full space of the microSD card? I know raspi-config allows you to expand to use full sd card, however there is nothing of the sort for kali.

Comment: You will have to do it manually i guess. Here is a simple guide. http://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions

Comment: @dastaan: Would you mind adding that as an answer?

Comment: I installed Kali on a 16 Gig card. The minimum ARM install from Offensive Security is less than 4G. After running apt-get update; then the "tasksel" command, I was given further auto install instructions for: Top 10 tools, Wireless Tools, etc. All installed with no problem or requirement for resizing petitions.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Added.

Answer (score 2):

Kali linux for Pi can be found on this link : http://docs.kali.org/kali-on-arm/install-kali-linux-arm-raspberry-pi with instructions to follow in order to make it work on Rpi.

As far as, re sizing partition(s) is(are) concerned, you will have do it manually. You can follow this guide. It's pretty straight forward. I used it while re sizing my Ubuntu rootfs. This works for any linux distro pretty much .Link : http://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions

---

### Edit:

One of the alternate solution could be grabbing `raspi-config` package from raspbian repo and install it on Kali Pi since both are debian based distros, it should work out of the box. Again, I've not tested it but it should work in theory.

Here are the steps :

1. `wget http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspi-config/raspi-config_20150706_all.deb`
2. `sudo gdebi raspi-config_20150706_all.deb`

Raspi-config utility should get installed by following these steps.

Try running `sudo raspi-config` to check.

Hope it helps.

Comment: using raspi-config destroyed my partition table, it showed in gpart that I was using all of the space however when i rebooted I still only showed having 29mb free in file manager. I lost everything I had just done setting up, oh well. I have decided on next go round I will try using gpart to resize the partition...

Comment: @user32950 That's interesting. I was able to make it work on my ubuntu just fine.