# Expand file system Kali Linux on SD card of 16GB

Tags: raspi-config, kali

I want to expand my filesystem, so I tried to follow [this](http://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions) tutorial to expand it, but it did not work.

[image]

I had to fix it.
To expand the file system of my SD-card of 16 Gb, I had to install `gparted` and move the partition to the entire size of my SD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: [Installing Kali Pi using all available storage space?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/33646/42034)

If you try download the `raspi-config`, please use the newest version [raspi-config_20160322_all.deb](http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspi-config/raspi-config_20160322_all.deb)

@Edit:
I found working script for Kali:

```
wget -O /boot/raspi-expand-rootfs.sh http://dl.linhost.info/file1/raspi-expand-rootfs.sh
chmod +x /boot/raspi-expand-rootfs.sh
sh /boot/raspi-expand-rootfs.sh
```

Source: https://linhost.info/2015/05/expand-the-root-partition-in-kali-linux-for-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: i have installed it but don't work expand file system

Comment: So you need to follow this guide: http://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions

Comment: i had modified a question, because i can't to do :(

Comment: If you are doing it on Raspberry Pi follow this section: http://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions#Manually_resizing_the_SD_card_on_Raspberry_Pi otherwise use another sections.

Comment: ok, when i run 'W' to write the new partition table, return me error:


Re-reading the partition table failed.:Device or resource Busy

Comment: please @Huczu , see my error :( i can't fix it :(

Comment: There is working script for it: `wget -O /boot/raspi-expand-rootfs.sh http://dl.linhost.info/file1/raspi-expand-rootfs.sh` `chmod +x /boot/raspi-expand-rootfs.sh` `sh /boot/raspi-expand-rootfs.sh`

Comment: i can't expand fileSystem when i run OS in SD, return me always same error, the resource are busy, i should be run a live OS of linux from USB and expand SD from live kali, sould work?
i try to follow http://www.instructables.com/id/Boot-the-Raspberry-Pi-from-USB/to boot from usb, but don't open usb boot

Comment: You can expand it when OS is running, this solution should work. Maybe turn off GUI?. You cannot boot raspberry from USB because it can only be booted from SD card. If you got live OS of linux try boot it on PC and mount your sdcard and expand file system.

Comment: yes, this evening try it!

Answer (score 5):

A quicker solution:

- Run `apt-get install gparted`
- GUI pops up
- Select ext4 + right click + "resize/move"
- Get all available space + "resize"
- "Apply All Operations"

Answer (score 2):

This will do it ... `sudo kalipi-config`

Comment: This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on [GParted](http://gparted.org/) with another computer. Open GParted, go to your SD card, unmount it, right click, and press resize/something.